# Oracle - Filter records based on input value

Tags: sql, oracle

In below sql statement, value for the person_id is dynamically passed.

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id = '&PERSON_ID';
```

There is a requirement, when user enters % for person_id, all records should be returned. Simply it should execute following query:

```
SELECT * FROM person;
```

Can anyone know the trick?

Comment: Is that safe if I use `Like` statement? `SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id LIKE '&PERSON_ID';`

Comment: where '&PERSON_ID' in (person_id,'%')?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Case statement in where clause to trick it.

If variable PERSON_ID is '%' then it will just equal to the same column, it's like 1 = 1 is true.

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id = (CASE WHEN '&PERSON_ID' = '%' THEN person_id ELSE '&PERSON_ID' END);
```

If variable PERSON_ID is empty not 'null', it will still display all result just like the below .

```
SELECT * FROM person;
```

Comment: And what if it *is not* null, and you have IDs that contain each other, like: '12', '123', '1234'?

Comment: Good catch! please see my update where i use case statement instead in where clause.